# What do you call a dog without a owner?

Tags: word-request

I remember there was an adjective for this kind of dogs, but I forgot what it was. It sounds like "scavenge", but it doesn't start by "s". I have the word on the tip of my tongue, but I can't remember it. A dog without a owner roaming the streets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common way to refer to this would be [stray](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stray) dog--a dog without an owner, whether because it got lost, was abandoned, etc.

You might also see [feral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feral), but that would imply a dog that was born wild and not ever accustomed to humans.

Comment: "feral" can also mean an animal that has been on its own so long -- perhaps for years -- that it has lost all socialization to humans. I would not use it for a dog that was simply lost.

Comment: I have also heard "homeless" and "ownerless" used in such cases.

Comment: While I do believe this is correct (+1), the OP said that word does not being with an "s." Also, "feral" doesn't really apply to what the OP is asking...